# Parenthesis Highlight but for Lua style languages (emacs)

Tags: emacs

In languages like R, C which use {} to delimit blocks, emacs's paren-mode works really nicely. Helps me locate where I am and whether my {} are balanced.

But Lua, uses 'end' to delimit functions, if then blocks, for loops etc.

Is there a similar highlight mode for that in emacs? I would rather not rely on the indentation.

Thanks

Comment: Well it appears, Lua-block mode is useful. Not perfect, since one has to the beginning of 'end' to highlight.

Comment: Have you tried `smartparens`, I have not used with `Lua-style` languages but apparently it can highlight such blocks. See this blogpost (http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/11/01/highlight-matching-delimiters-with-smartparens/)

Comment: `paren-mode` can work with such blocks.  Major modes which use SMIE get that "for free", for example.